# Corona tabBar creation fails

Tags: lua, coronasdk, tabbar, corona-storyboard

In my menu.lua I have the following code:`storyboard.gotoScene( "vegScreen" )`, meaning: vegetable screen/menu

In the scene:createScene function of my vegScreen.lua I try to create a tabBar with 2 tabs. Using the following code:

```
local tabButtons = {
    {
        width = 50, height = 40,
        defaultFile = "assets/tabIcon.png",
        overFile = "assets/tabIcon-down.png",
        label = "Per catagory",
        onPress = function() storyboard.gotoScene( "catagory" ); end,
        selected = true
    },
    {
        width = 50, height = 40,
        defaultFile = "assets/tabIcon.png",
        overFile = "assets/tabIcon-down.png",
        label = "All products",
        onPress = function() storyboard.gotoScene( "all" ); end,
    }
}

productBar = widget.newTabBar{  -- line 82
    top = 65,
    width = display.contentWidth,
    backgroundFile = "assets/tabBar_background.png",
    tabSelectedLeftFile = "assets/tabBar_background.png",
    tabSelectedMiddleFile = "assets/tabBar_background.png",
    tabSelectedRightFile = "assets/tabBar_background.png",
    tabSelectedFrameWidth = 20,
    tabSelectedFrameHeight = 52,
    buttons = tabButtons
}

group:insert(productBar)
```

Using this code I get the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aekla.png

Line 82 in vegScreen.lua is where I create the new tabBar ( productBar = widget.newTabBar )

Though I don't know if the images I created are used correctly, it should show me something right? I have the module require statements at the top of my vegScreen.lua file (for storyboard and widget), created the catagory.lua and all.lua files which are located in the same folder as the vegScreen.lua and I have defined the group variable. Could somebody help me out? The error doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: can you mark line 37 of vegscreen.lua as I have for line 82; also more specific than "using this code", do you see this traceback as soon as you create the scene the first time?

Comment: Line 37 is the scene:createScene function, in which the code above is placed. I currently 'solved' the problem by removing storyboard.purgeScene(storyboard.getCurrentSceneName() ) from my scene:exitScene function. But then a whole new ....storm of errors rolls down on me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer but I solved my problem. I had created files in which I used code to load content. I think the issue with that lies in not being able to add content to existing titanium views.

So what I did was deleted those files and created the views through code, which works like a charm.